# Precision of a experiment of algorithm

Tags: algorithm, statistics

I am reading a book and there is a paragraph about a certain probabilistic algorithm.

> However, running the same input file several times yields the same
>   running time, to within 1%, each time.

Sincerely, I do not understand what the author wants to say with the expression "to within 1%". Could you help me please?

Comment: For example the average running time was 100 seconds, the minimum running time was 99 seconds, and the max 101 seconds.

Comment: Is the name and the author of the book a secret ;-) ?